# Nativescript Detect Orientation without auto rotate screen content

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript

In Nativescript Angular, Is there anyway to detect orientation change and not allow content auto rotate but handling the content rotation manually? For example when rotating orientation from portrait to landscape, I want the content on the screen to stay still but i need to know that the screen is currently in landscape mode.

Im using [nativescript-orientation](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-orientation) plugin but this only allow me to disable the rotation. Once the rotation is disabled i could not detect the orientation change when the screen is landscape or portrait.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect the orientation by yourself then you have to get the sensor data. I have never done this myself so I will just tell you where you can start. For IOS, you have get the sensor data from `coremotion`. You would require the data from the accelerometer and magnetometer sensors's data.

You can use the plugin `nativescript-coremotion` or You can directly access the IOS native methods yourself to do it.